Unpacking into several lists of fixed length
I have a list of data (of varying type) that I need to process. It has fixed length and I know which index holds what data, so currently I do something like
for x in data[:13]:
  do_stuff(x)
for x in data[13:21]:
  do_other_stuff(x)
...

I know I can split the data manually like
list1 = data[:13]
list2 = data[13:21]
...

but I was wondering if there was a way to do it in one line similar to the normal list unpacking, maybe like
*list1[13], *list2[8], *rest = data


You don’t need the operator * nor [] on the left hand side to perform the necessary unpacking. You can unpack and repack by slicing in one line, then treat the individual lists differently. It depends on what you want to do to the individual lists.

There isn't a way to do what you want directly via slicing, but you could write a function that does this:
def split_list(src, split_sizes):
    ret_lists = []
    last_split = 0
    for s in split_sizes:
        next_split = s + last_split
        ret_lists.append(src[last_split:next_split])
        last_split = next_split

    ret_lists.append(src[last_split:])
    return ret_lists

Then, pass your expected sizes to this function as a list or tuple:
list1, list2, rest = split_list(data, [13, 8])

With example data:
data = list(range(25))

This function call gives the expected splits:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
[13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[21, 22, 23, 24]


This looks really nice, but since I only need this functionality once in the entire project, I will stick with what I have now.

a recursive generator option:
data = [i for i in range(100)]
chunks = [i + 1 for i in range(12)]

def yield_chunk(data, chunks):
    if data:
        if chunks:
            chunk = chunks.pop(0)
            yield data[:chunk]
            yield from yield_chunk(data[chunk:], chunks)
        else:
            yield data
            data = []

lists = {f"lists{i}": chunk for i, chunk in enumerate(yield_chunk(data, chunks))}

for key, value in lists.items():
    print(f"{key}: {value}")

output:
lists0: [0]
lists1: [1, 2]
lists2: [3, 4, 5]
lists3: [6, 7, 8, 9]
lists4: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
lists5: [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
lists6: [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
lists7: [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]
lists8: [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44]
lists9: [45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54]
lists10: [55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65]
lists11: [66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77]
lists12: [78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]


As others have rightly said, there's no built-in mechanism for this.
You could use a very simple generator like this:
def do_the_splits(data, splits):
    s = 0
    for e in splits:
        yield data[s:e]
        s = e


DATA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

# note that the number of variables being assigned to must match the length of the 2nd parameter
a, b = do_the_splits(DATA, [3, 8])

print(a)  # 0:3
print(b)  # 3:8

Output:
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]


Yes you can do this by slicing in one-liner:
list1, list2, ••• = data[:13], data[13:21], ••• #[1]
The list is sliced into multiple lists and stored into the various variables.

[1] The index pattern follows the OP’s index pattern closely.

Worth mentioning that there's no functional benefit to writing this as a one-liner and certainly contradicts Zen of Python

well, that's just what I have right now in a less readable way
